# Swift 2.0 Как очистить экран от анимации (refreshView = ? )

Tags: swift

```
         if (self.start.image == UIImage(named: "0005.png")) 
         { print("0005 нашлось");

    for loopAniView in 1...5 {  
         let AniView_0005 = UIImageView()
        AniView_0005.image = UIImage(named: "0005.png")
        AniView_0005.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)
        self.view.addSubview(AniView_0005)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.8, delay: 0.2, options: [ .AllowUserInteraction], animations:
            {  
                AniView_0005.frame = CGRectMake(200, 240, 230, 230)
            }, completion: nil)
```

//... completion: nil) применен именно для заполнения экрана
  //анимация запускается неоднократно и заполняет экран iOS в произвольном   порядке
  //имеется батон (button) который запускает

func refreshView()  {
  print("button сработал");

// что можно применить  чтобы очистить экран от накопившихся изображений
  // опробовано =
  // self.removeAnimate()
  // setNeedsDisplay()
  // AniView_0005.removeAnimate()
  // self.view.willRemoveSubview(Ani_0005.image)
  // self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  // exit(0) // хорошая штука...
  // self.refreshView() // гонит цикл потом выдает -
  // warning: could not load any Objective-C class information.
  // This will significantly reduce the quality of type information   available.
  // self.viewDidLoad()
  // self.viewWillAppear()
  // self.view.layer.removeAllAnimations
  // AniView_0005.layer.removeAllAnimations()  // = !
  // self.view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
  //view.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
  //Ani0005.layer.sublayers?.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
  // или = ОШ или = ничего не происходит...
   print("remove_started = ?")

}

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить tag для UIImage для опознания.
И удаление:

```
for view in self.view.subviews {
        if view.tag == 5000 && view is UIImageView {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```